# replace current image with new dataurl fineuploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fine-uploader

Good Day,

I was finally able to create crop functionality for my image uploader using fineupload.

I have set my fineuploader to `autoUpload: false,` so I could crop the image before it passes to the server currently heres what I have..

heres my code for catching the crop button and initializing the cropper

```
$(document).on('click','.qq-upload-crop',function(e){ 
    var id = $(this).parent('li').attr('qq-file-id');
    var x =  manualUploader.getFile(id);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#cimgx').attr('src',e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(x);
    setTimeout(initCropper, 1000);
    $('#crop-modal').modal('show');
});


function initCropper(){
     $('#cimgx').cropper({
      cropBoxResizable:true,
      autoCrop:true,
      minCropBoxWidth:600,
      minCropBoxHeight:400,
    });
}
```

[image]

And if I click Crop

another modal shows up.

[image]

and when I click the crop button, using this code

```
$('#crop').on('click',function(e){
  var x = $('#cimgx').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  console.log(x);
})
```

I get the dataUrl in return.

now I wanted to replace the current initially uploaded image with my cropped image from cropperjs ..

how can I replace the data to be pass please.. Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question

### 1) You want to replace the image of original img element

```
$('#original_image').attr('src',x);
```

### 2) More likely you want to upload cropped image to the server

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="form_id" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="upload_media" id="upload_media" type="file" class="hidden">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#crop').on('click',function(e){
  var x = $('#cimgx').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  console.log(x);
})
var form_data = new FormData($('#form_id')[0]);
form_data.set('upload_media', cropped_img_data, 'filename.jpg');


$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'upload.php',
data: form_data,
success: function(data) {
 console.log(data)
}
})
```

**PHP**

```
$filename = $_FILES['upload_media']['name'];
$img = $_FILES['upload_media']['tmp_name'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Happy coding!